# WebClient.DownloadFileAsync - How do I keep track of the total amount of bytes downloaded when downloading multiple files?

Tags: c#, file, webclient

So I'm trying to download two images and just for demonstration I've checked their sizes and summed it up to a variable called `totalBytes`.

I want to keep track of how much has been downloaded out of those total bytes so I can calculate the percentage by taking `downloaded` / totalBytes * 100

But I have no idea how to keep track of the mount of bytes that has been downloaded.

```
public static int totalBytes = 1378954;
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var images = new List<string>
    {
        "http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-HTvSYzA-pO4/UgQb4Zh_u0I/AAAAAAAAEuI/XwhtogT_1tA/s1600/3+cute2.jpg",
        "http://getwallpapers.com/wallpaper/full/7/7/0/74728.jpg"
    };
    foreach (var image in images)
    {
        int i = 0;
        using (var wc = new WebClient())
        {
            wc.DownloadProgressChanged += Wc_DownloadProgressChanged;
            wc.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(image), $"image{i}.png");
            i++;

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

    }
}

private static void Wc_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Downloaded: {e.BytesReceived} out of {totalBytes}");
}
```

Comment: What is wrong with this code? It should work and write received bytes to console. If you need total bytes received for both images keep a reference to them (put received size of images in an array) and whenever `Wc_DownloadProgressChanged` is fired use new data to recalculate total received bytes.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean, I do want to keep track of the total amount received.

Comment: Just use a separate field `private static int _bytesReceived = 0` and add to it `e.BytesReceived` inside the `Wc_DownloadProgressChanged` method as it has been already said above. And, probably, at least add a `volatile` specifier to that `_bytesReceived` field to avoid possible concurrency issues.

Comment: That doesn't work, `_bytesReceived ` gets way bigger than the total value

Comment: Oh, yes. Sorry - didn't check the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-Us/dotnet/api/system.net.downloadprogresschangedeventargs?view=netframework-4.8) that it is actually more like `TotalBytesReceived` (well, good naming is important...). Also, the `volatile` part was completely wrong (I wanted to say https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.interlocked.add?view=netframework-4.8 but somehow got sidetracked).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you do not intend to actually start downloading files in parallel (as you dispose the `WebClient` before starting another download), the problem can be solved with two field

1. One to store the current total
2. Another to store the previous ReceivedByte value

   ```
   private static long _totalBytesReceivedAllFiles = 0;

   private static long _previousBytesReceivedForCurrentFile = 0;

   private static object _lock = new Object();

   private static void Wc_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
   {
       // There are no guarantees in the documentation that such events are serialized and can't execute in parallel even for a single file,
       // thus we will use lock to at least partially serialize it and ensure atomic field access. 
       // !!!It is not intended to handle actual parallel downloads!!!
       lock (_lock)
       {
           _totalBytesReceivedAllFiles = _totalBytesReceivedAllFiles - _previousBytesReceivedForCurrentFile + e.BytesReceived;
           _previousBytesReceivedForCurrentFile = e.BytesReceived;
           Console.WriteLine($"Downloaded: {_totalBytesReceivedAllFiles} out of {totalBytes}");
           if (e.ProgressPercentage == 100)
           {
               Console.WriteLine("Current file downloaded");
               _previousBytesReceivedForCurrentFile = 0;
           }
       }
   }
   ```

If on the other hand you want to start downloads truly in parallel, then you will have to

1. Not to dispose (in the loop!) the client, for obvious reasons.
2. Use a per-file Wc_DownloadProgressChanged with [closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271440/captured-variable-in-a-loop-in-c-sharp) to have an actual per-file `_previousBytesReceivedForCurrentFile`